# masking an imshow, or imshow with RGBA

Tags: python, imshow

A dataframe, which should be considered a matrix, contains values 0, 1, 2.

With imshow, I get a nice image. I can use a cmap with 3 discrete colors.

I want to highlight few rows, so visually I want to have those rows with alpha=1 and the other with alpha=0.1 .

Should I create the image myself, creating a matrix with RGBA entries?
Is there a more straight-forward way?

With Kind Regards,
Oren

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way to do that with Layer Images.
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/layer_images.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-layer-images-py

Apparently I can imshow the matrix with the intended highlighted colors. And on top of that, add a imshow with values that are either the same, where I want to highlight, or white otherwise. I then make sure to have alpha=0.5 for example, for the second imshow.